# How do I count occurrence of unique values inside a list

Tags: python, arrays, variables, loops, unique

So I'm trying to make this program that will ask the user for input and store the values in an array / list.
Then when a blank line is entered it will tell the user how many of those values are unique.
I'm building this for real life reasons and not as a problem set.

```
enter: happy
enter: rofl
enter: happy
enter: mpg8
enter: Cpp
enter: Cpp
enter:
There are 4 unique words!
```

My code is as follows:

```
# ask for input
ipta = raw_input("Word: ")

# create list 
uniquewords = [] 
counter = 0
uniquewords.append(ipta)

a = 0   # loop thingy
# while loop to ask for input and append in list
while ipta: 
  ipta = raw_input("Word: ")
  new_words.append(input1)
  counter = counter + 1

for p in uniquewords:
```

..and that's about all I've gotten so far.
I'm not sure how to count the unique number of words in a list?
If someone can post the solution so I can learn from it, or at least show me how it would be great, thanks!

Answer (score 402):

In addition, use [collections.Counter](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to refactor your code:

```
from collections import Counter

words = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a']

Counter(words).keys() # equals to list(set(words))
Counter(words).values() # counts the elements' frequency
```

Output:

```py
['a', 'c', 'b']
[2, 1, 1]
```

Comment: Not an answer to Joel's question, but *exactly* what I was looking for, thanks!

Comment: `Counter(words).values()` is nice. We are assuming the the count is in the order of first appearance of the list of words? I mean, I'm assuming the count will give us the count of a, then b, then c, then d...

Comment: Note if you want to represent this as a dict like `count_dict = {'a': 2, 'b': 1, 'c': 1}` you can do `count_dict = dict(Counter(words).items())`

Comment: @Peter `.items()` is not needed. `dict(Counter(words))`

Comment: You can do `sum(Counter(words).values())` to get the total

Comment: I think most answers diverge from the initial goal, and that is actually good. Lots of people — such as myself — draw value from these. In any case, the initial goal was to identify  unique words, remember? "**how many of those values are unique**" So I would propose `len([k for k,v in Counter(words).items() if v == 1])`. If you want the actual words, just ditch the wrapping `len()` and go with `[k for k,v in Counter(words).items() if v == 1]`. The fact that @JoelAqu doesn't know _how_ to ask what he _really_ wants is a whole different matter. He wants `len(set(...`, as per @codebox's.

Answer (score 303):

You can use a [set](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset) to remove duplicates, and then the [len](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#len) function to count the elements in the set:

```
len(set(new_words))
```

Comment: This method is more efficient when one just wants to know the number of unique elements in a list.

Answer (score 88):

`values, counts = np.unique(words, return_counts=True)`

#### More Detail

```py
import numpy as np

words = ['b', 'a', 'a', 'c', 'c', 'c']
values, counts = np.unique(words, return_counts=True)
```

The function [numpy.unique](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) returns **sorted** unique elements of the input list together with their counts:

```py
['a', 'b', 'c']
[2, 1, 3]
```

Comment: Four years after https://stackoverflow.com/a/12282286/2932052 - what makes this solution any better?

Comment: It gives more refined info.

Comment: It is always nice to put some additional effort into the answer by at least providing a link to the [documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) of the suggested function.

Comment: @Jeyekomon Yes, a nice addition. You may edit the answer if you wish.

Answer (score 20):

Use a [set](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#set):

```
words = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a']
unique_words = set(words)             # == set(['a', 'b', 'c'])
unique_word_count = len(unique_words) # == 3
```

Armed with this, your solution could be as simple as:

```
words = []
ipta = raw_input("Word: ")

while ipta:
  words.append(ipta)
  ipta = raw_input("Word: ")

unique_word_count = len(set(words))

print "There are %d unique words!" % unique_word_count
```

Comment: Good explanation, sometimes it's better do do it single step first, so there is anough space for comments ;)

Answer (score 14):

```
aa="XXYYYSBAA"
bb=dict(zip(list(aa),[list(aa).count(i) for i in list(aa)]))
print(bb)
# output:
# {'X': 2, 'Y': 3, 'S': 1, 'B': 1, 'A': 2}
```

Comment: Please explain how this is different from the other answers

Comment: This is like a `Counter` but really inefficient cause most of the counts are thrown away, and `list.count()` is O(n) anyway. You don't even need to convert `aa` to list at all. See [Vidul's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12288109/4518341) instead.

Answer (score 6):

For ndarray there is a numpy method called [unique](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html):

```
np.unique(array_name)
```

Examples:

```
>>> np.unique([1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3])
array([1, 2, 3])
>>> a = np.array([[1, 1], [2, 3]])
>>> np.unique(a)
array([1, 2, 3])
```

For a Series there is a function call [value_counts()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html):

```
Series_name.value_counts()
```

Answer (score 5):

If you would like to have a histogram of unique values here's oneliner

```
import numpy as np    
unique_labels, unique_counts = np.unique(labels_list, return_counts=True)
labels_histogram = dict(zip(unique_labels, unique_counts))
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `get` method:

```
lst = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'd', 'd']

dictionary = {}
for item in lst:
    dictionary[item] = dictionary.get(item, 0) + 1
    
print(dictionary)
```

Output:

```
{'a': 1, 'b': 1, 'c': 3, 'd': 2}
```

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
import pandas as pd
#List with all words
words=[]

#Code for adding words
words.append('test')


#When Input equals blank:
pd.Series(words).nunique()
```

It returns how many unique values are in a list

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! It looks like this solution assumes using `pandas` framework. It would be better to mention it in the answer as it may be unclear for other users.

Answer (score 1):

```
ipta = raw_input("Word: ") ## asks for input
words = [] ## creates list
unique_words = set(words)
```

Answer (score 1):

Although a set is the easiest way, you could also use a dict and use `some_dict.has(key)` to populate a dictionary with only unique keys and values.

Assuming you have already populated `words[]` with input from the user, create a dict mapping the unique words in the list to a number:

```
word_map = {}
i = 1
for j in range(len(words)):
    if not word_map.has_key(words[j]):
        word_map[words[j]] = i
        i += 1                                                             
num_unique_words = len(new_map) # or num_unique_words = i, however you prefer
```

Answer (score 1):

Other method by using pandas

```
import pandas as pd

LIST = ["a","a","c","a","a","v","d"]
counts,values = pd.Series(LIST).value_counts().values, pd.Series(LIST).value_counts().index
df_results = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(values,counts)),columns=["value","count"])
```

You can then export results in any format you want

Answer (score 0):

The following should work. The lambda function filter out the duplicated words.

```
inputs=[]
input = raw_input("Word: ").strip()
while input:
    inputs.append(input)
    input = raw_input("Word: ").strip()
uniques=reduce(lambda x,y: ((y in x) and x) or x+[y], inputs, [])
print 'There are', len(uniques), 'unique words'
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a set myself, but here's yet another way:

```
uniquewords = []
while True:
    ipta = raw_input("Word: ")
    if ipta == "":
        break
    if not ipta in uniquewords:
        uniquewords.append(ipta)
print "There are", len(uniquewords), "unique words!"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ipta = raw_input("Word: ") ## asks for input
words = [] ## creates list

while ipta: ## while loop to ask for input and append in list
  words.append(ipta)
  ipta = raw_input("Word: ")
  words.append(ipta)
#Create a set, sets do not have repeats
unique_words = set(words)

print "There are " +  str(len(unique_words)) + " unique words!"
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my own version

```
def unique_elements():
    elem_list = []
    dict_unique_word = {}
    for i in range(5):# say you want to check for unique words from five given words
        word_input = input('enter element: ')
        elem_list.append(word_input)
        if word_input not in dict_unique_word:
            dict_unique_word[word_input] = 1
        else:
            dict_unique_word[word_input] += 1
    return elem_list, dict_unique_word
result_1, result_2 = unique_elements() 
# result_1 holds the list of all inputted elements
# result_2 contains unique words with their count
print(result_2)
```

Comment: Could you provide an explanation of your code and how this solves the question being asked?

Comment: Ok. The code receives inputs up to a range set by the user, appends them into the `elem_list`, and uses `dict_unique_word` dictionary to get number of unique words received.