# How to make a counting function that returns the number of elements in a list

Tags: python

I am trying to make a function that counts elements in a list and I am using Python for that. The program should accept a list like `[a, a, a, b, b, c, c, c, c]` and returns a value `[3, 2, 4]` but I am having trouble. What should I do?

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12282232/how-do-i-count-unique-values-inside-an-array-in-python

Comment: `print( [lst.count(i) for i in set(lst)] ) ` ?

Comment: How will you know that 3 belongs to a, 2 to b and 4 to c?

Comment: use `collections.Counter`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to count the occurrences of a list item?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2600191/how-to-count-the-occurrences-of-a-list-item)

Comment: What should the function do given `[a, a, a, b, b, a]`? Return `[4, 2]` or `[3, 2, 1]`?

Comment: Yes I could use a built in function but I am trying not to

Answer (score 3):

If when given `['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'a']` you want `[3, 2, 1]`:

```
import itertools
result = [len(list(iterable)) for _, iterable in itertools.groupby(my_list)]
```

Comment: just an addition: `[(k, sum(1 for _ in v)) for k, v in itertools.groupby(my_list)]` is an example how to get also the mapping of the counted elements.

Answer (score 1):

Use a dict and make a counter out of it.

```
a,b,c = "a","b","c"
inp = [a,a,a,b,b,c,c,c,c]
dic = {}
for i in inp:
    if i in dic:
        dic[i]+=1
    else:
        dic[i] = 1
print(dic)  #Dict with input values and count of them
print(dic.values())  #Count of values in the dict
```

Remember that this change the order of input list.
To keep the order intact, use OrderedDict method from Collections library.

```
from collections import OrderedDict
a,b,c = "a","b","c"
inp = [a,a,a,b,b,c,c,c,c]
dic = OrderedDict()
for i in inp:
    if i in dic:
        dic[i]+=1
    else:
        dic[i] = 1
print(dic)
print(dic.values())
```