# Count the unique elements in a list without set

Tags: python, arrays

I am currently attempting to make a program that will count and print the number of unique elements in a list.

My code:

```
def solution(N, A):
    yee = 1   

    for i in range(1, len(A)):
        j = 0
        for j in range(i):
            if(A[i] == A[j]):
                yee-=1
        if(i==j+1):
            yee +=1

    print(yee)


N = int(input())
A = []
n = 0
for e in input().split():
    if(n<N):
        A.append(int(e))
        n+=1

solution(N, A)
```

With the list containing (1 2 3 1 4 2 5 6 7 8) the output is supposed to be 6. However, my program is returning 8. I believe this is due to the program counting the 1 and 2, even though they are not technically unique in the problem. I'm sure it's and easy fix, but I just can't seem to figure it out. Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Forgot to mention that the N takes the input for how many numbers will be in array A

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I count unique values inside a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12282232/how-do-i-count-unique-values-inside-a-list)

Answer (score 3):

The only way you would get the output of 6 for `(1, 2, 3, 1, 4, 2, 5, 6, 7, 8)` would be if you wanted to count the number of elements that appear *exactly once*, as opposed to the number of unique elements (there are 8 elements, of which two are repeated more than once).

You could do this in a one-liner:

```
def num_single_elements(A):
    return len(list(e for e in A if A.count(e) == 1))
```

Comment: By the way, `list(generator expr)` can just be `[a list comprehension]`.

Comment: I figured I was making the code too complicated, now it turns out I checking for the wrong things too lol. Thank you so much!!

Comment: Similarly: `sum(1 for x in A if A.count(x) == 1)`

Answer (score 0):

Similarly if you need to keep check of the number of elements further on in your code, I like dictionary comprehension for this kind of problem:

```
dict_A = {x:A.count(x) for x in A}
print(len([x for x in dict_A if dict_A[x] == 1]))
```

Answer (score 0):

As Green Cloak Guy said, you seem to be looking for the number of elements which appear exactly once, and his answer contains a solution to that. Here's a simple solution for finding the number of unique elements:

```
def unique_elements(A):
    return len([ 1 for (index, a) in enumerate(A) if A.index(a) == index ])
```

The idea here is to count up the first occurrence of each unique value.

- `enumerate` allows us to get the index of the item, as well as the item itself, as we iterate;
- `A.index(a)` gives the index of the first time the value of `a` appears in `A`.

So, if we count up all the times `index` equals `A.index(a)`, we're counting the first time an item appears which has never appeared before, which is equal to the number of unique elements.