# Python list comprehension count occurences

Tags: python

Suppose I have a list (or in this case a `Series`) that looks like this

```
[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,6,6,6,6,7,8,8,8,8,8]
```

I now want to convert this to a `dict` such that the key of the dict is the value of the list (here `1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8`) and that the value of the dict is the amount that the value of the list occures (here `7, 3, 9, 4, 1, 5`).

I'd like to use a simple oneliner/list-comprehension but this topic is new to me for Python

Comment: `import collections; counts = collections.Counter(your_list)`

Comment: From ```collections import Counter``` and then ```d = Counter([1,1,1,1,1,1,1,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,6,6,6,6,7,8,8,8,8,8])```.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12282232/how-do-i-count-unique-values-inside-a-list