# Count of outputs of a program

Tags: python

In a python program I have a single output. I want the count of all unique values of that output of that program.I do not want to use dataframe because the input size is too big.
I am new to python and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: please read how to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Solution

You can do it using any of the following three methods. Since, you did not provide any working code or dummy data, I made my own. Although the three methods essentially produce the same result, the order of the unique-values printed is different for each method.

### Method-1

Using `set` and `list-comprehension` with `list.count()`.

```py
# Dummy Data
values = list('abcddanbcaeghfgba')
# expect:
# ('a', 4) ('b', 3) ('c', 2) 
# ('d', 2) ('e', 1) ('f', 1) 
# ('g', 2) ('h', 1) ('n', 1)

# Method-1
unique_values = set(values)
counts = [values.count(e) for e in unique_values]
print(*zip(unique_values, counts))
```

**Output**:

```
('a', 4) ('e', 1) ('g', 2) ('b', 3) ('d', 2) ('h', 1) ('f', 1) ('n', 1) ('c', 2)
```

### Method-2

Using `collections.Counter`.

```py
from collections import Counter

# Method-2
unique_values = Counter(values).keys() 
counts = Counter(values).values()

print(*zip(unique_values, counts))
```

**Output**:

```
('a', 4) ('b', 3) ('c', 2) ('d', 2) ('n', 1) ('e', 1) ('g', 2) ('h', 1) ('f', 1)
```

### Method-3

Using `numpy.unique()`.

```py
import numpy as np

# Method-3
unique_values, counts = np.unique(values, return_counts=True)

print(*zip(unique_values, counts))
```

**Output**:

```
('a', 4) ('b', 3) ('c', 2) ('d', 2) ('e', 1) ('f', 1) ('g', 2) ('h', 1) ('n', 1)
```

Reference:

- [How do I count unique values inside a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12282232/how-do-i-count-unique-values-inside-a-list)

Comment: @KoustabhGhosh Could you please also **`vote up`** this answer? Thank you.