# Is there a way to calculate the number of occurrences of a string in a list without using a dictionary?

Tags: python

Is there another  way to calculate the number of occurrences without using a dictionary like this code?
I mean, I want the same result as this code but without the dict.

This code displays:

```
apple 3
bread 2
orange 1
```

Code:

```
txt = ["apple", "bread", "apple", "orange", "apple", "bread"]
dic ={}
for c in texte:
  lettres[c] = lettres.get(c, 0) + 1

for i in sorted(lettres):
 print(i,lettres.get(i))
```

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12282232/how-do-i-count-unique-values-inside-a-list

Comment: If you are concerned with only a specific element, use `list.count`.  If you want counts of all elements. use `Counter` from the `collections` module

Comment: what is wrong with a dict?

Comment: The simplest way to get the same result is just `texte`. Produces the same NameError.

Answer (score 0):

If the charset is known and limited (lower case ASCII alphabet for example), you could allocate an array, and increment the count corresponding to the index of a character every time you see it. This, however, is waste of space since you may never encounter some characters at all.

Answer (score -1):

**Option 1 : Use counters**

```
from collections import Counter

txt = ["apple", "bread", "apple", "orange", "apple", "bread"]

keys = Counter(txt).keys() # equals to list(set(txt))
occ = Counter(txt).values() # counts the number of occurrences
```

Output:

```
['apple', 'bread', 'orange']
[3, 2, 1]
```

**Option 2: Use count and set**

```
occ = {i: txt.count(i) for i in set(txt)}
```

Output:

```
{"apple": 3, "bread": 2, "orange": 1}
```

If you want to just print it without saving in a dictionary, use this:

```
for i in set(txt):
   print(i, txt.count(i))
```

Comment: Counter is a dict, OP said she didn't want a dict.

Comment: OP doesn't want to manually use a dictionary to get the occurrences. Anyway, option 2 can be modified to save the occurrences in another format.

Comment: Option 2 is a dict as well. Either OP or you are wrong, and since we can't read her mind, we will go by the phrasing she used, which is not to use a dict.