# get two characters, count and print from a .txt file

Tags: python

The program I wrote is terrible so if anyone can make a different py and give me some pointers well thanks a bunch!

What I would like help on is to print only the first two characters of a word and if those same characters repeat hold them to a count. It's like a Zipf distribution but for the first two letters for every word. The example is how I would like the output. Here is an example from this text and its for show!

text file = "Here is an example from this text and its for show!"

an 2

He 1

is 1

ex 1

fr 1

th 1

te 1

it 1

fo 1

sh 1

total 11

```
 file = open("C:\python37\paradise.txt", 'r') 

 while 1: 
   
     # read by character 
     char = file.read(2)
     if not char:  
         break
       
     print(char) 

 file.close()
```

Comment: cross-posted at [python-forum.io](https://python-forum.io/Thread-get-two-characters-count-and-print-from-a-txt-file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to read *character by character* because that will require a lot of effort. Here's a better way:

```py
# dictionary to store count of each word (2 characters) eg. "an": 2
wordDict = {}

file = open("paradise.txt", 'r')
# read each line in file
for line in file:
    # read each word in line
    for word in line.split():
        # get only first two letters of word
        word = word[:2]
        # If word is not in dictionary then add it
        if word not in wordDict:
          wordDict[word] = 1
        # else increment the count
        else:
          wordDict[word] += 1

file.close()

# print all values
for key, val in wordDict.items():
  print(key, val)

# print total
print(f"Total: {sum(wordDict.values())}")
```

**Explanation:**
To store the count, we create a dictionary where keys are the words and values are their counts. E.g:

```py
{
  "an": 2,
  "He": 1
}
```

Then, we read the file content **line by line**. We split the line into words and get the first two letters of each word.

Next, we add those words in our dictionary `wordDict` with their respective counts.

**Note:**
It is suggested to open files using `with` keyword.

```py
with open('paradise.txt') as file:
    ...
```

This way, file is closed automatically.

Comment: Thanks for any help Moosa, however I received this error with your code      wordDict[word] += 1
KeyError: 'of'

Comment: Sorry, I missed the **not** keyword while updating the code. The condition should be `if word not in wordDict:`. I will correct the mistake

Answer (score 0):

I would create a result list **results=[]** to which the two-letter chunks are added. Then I would count the occurrences of unique items in the result list.

Is that what you want?

Here is the link which will help you count unique items in a Python list:

[How do I count unique values inside a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12282232/how-do-i-count-unique-values-inside-a-list)

The answer by [Vidul](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1367611/vidul) is what relates to your question:

"In addition, use `collections.Counter` to refactor your code:

```
from collections import Counter

words = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a']

Counter(words).keys() # equals to list(set(words))
Counter(words).values() # counts the elements' frequency

Output:

['a', 'c', 'b']
[2, 1, 1]
```

"

The **words** list in Vidul's example would be **results** in yours.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this simply by loading the whole text file into an array of separate words using space as a delimiter.

Once you have all the words in an array you can loop through the array and only return the first 2 letters of each word using an **array operator [:2]**. From here you can add each set of 2 to a dictionary and count up.

**Example code below that works as well as the output**:

```
filePath = "C:\\Users\\Oddity\\Documents\\Python\\STACKEXCHANGE\\test.txt"

## Read file into list of each word as a seperate entry
data = []
with open(filePath, 'r') as file:
    data = file.read().replace('\n', ' ').split(' ')

    ## Loop through each word and retreive the first two characters
    ## then update the dict
    characters = {}
    for each in data:
        if each[:2] in characters:
            characters[each[:2]] += 1
        else:
            characters[each[:2]] = 1

    print(characters)

    file.close()
```

**Output:**

```
{'He': 2, 'is': 2, 'an': 4, 'ex': 2, 'fr': 2, 'th': 2, 'te': 2, 'it': 2, 'fo': 2, 'sh': 2}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
file = open("C:\python37\paradise.txt", 'r') 
wordDictionary = {}
keys = []
para = file.read() 
for line in para:
   for word in line,split():
     letters =word[0:2]
     if letters in keys:
        wordDictionary[letters]++
     else:
        keys.append(letters)
        wordDictionary[letters]=1
print (wordDictionary)
file.close()
```

This is a very simple way in which I open the file, read it and then iterate through every word. Then I get the first 2 letters. Then I check if those are in the keys of the dictionary(I maintaned a separate list). If yes I added one else I created a new record

Answer (score 0):

I hope this would solve :

[image: so]

[Click here](https://gist.github.com/aahnik/173d6fe9b00cbea7710130504d4c595d#gistcomment-3475704) to copy the code

Output:

```
 He : 1
 is : 1
 an : 2
 ex : 1
 fr : 1
 th : 1
 te : 1
 it : 1
 fo : 1
 sh : 1
```