# How to get count of non-repeating values in list

Tags: python

I know I can do something like [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12288109/1317018) to get number of occurrences of elements in the list:

```
from collections import Counter

words = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a']

Counter(words).keys() # equals to list(set(words))
Counter(words).values() # counts the elements' frequency
```

Outputs:

```
['a', 'c', 'b']
[2, 1, 1]
```

But I want to get the count 2 for `b` and `c` as `b` and `c` occur exactly once in the list.
Is there any way to do this in concise / pythonic way without using `Counter` or even using above output from `Counter`?

Answer (score -1):

You could just make an algorithm that does that, here is a one liner (thanks @d.b):

```py
sum(x for x in Counter(words).values() if x == 1)
```

Or more than one line:

```py
seen = []
count = 0

for word in words:
  if word not in seen:
    count += 1
    seen.append(word)
```

Comment: Why do a list lookup? Make `seen` a set, it's much cheaper to look up elements of a set.